# rows to change images with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i'm trying to achieve something like this.https://www.instrument.com/ its on last of the page. The 3 images are replacing by other 3 images and those 3 images are replacing with some other 3 images and the cycle continues.

```js
jQuery(function(i) {
  i(document).ready(function() {
    i(".images").each(function(e, a) {
      i(this).children("img").first().addClass("active").fadeIn().removeClass("in-active")
    }), setInterval(function() {
      i(".images").each(function(e, a) {
        var t;
        i(this).children("img").first().addClass("active").fadeIn().removeClass("in-active"), i(this).children("img").last().is(":visible") && (t = i(".images"), i(t).each(function(e, a) {
          i(a).children("img").removeClass("active"), i(a).children("img").addClass("in-active"), i(a).children("img").first().addClass("active").removeClass("in-active")
        })), i(this).children(".active").next().addClass("active").prev().removeClass("active").addClass("in-active"), i(".active").fadeIn(), i(".in-active").fadeOut();
        var s, c, n = (s = 1, c = 4500, Math.floor(Math.random() * (c - s + 1) + s));
        i(this).attr({
          id: "cycler_" + n
        })
      })
    }, 5e3)
  })
});
```

```css
.images img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="images">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1432821596592-e2c18b78144f?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8YmxvZ3xlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522199755839-a2bacb67c546?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NXx8YmxvZ3xlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1432821596592-e2c18b78144f?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8YmxvZ3xlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  </div>
  <div class="images">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1471107340929-a87cd0f5b5f3?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8YmxvZ3xlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497633762265-9d179a990aa6?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8OHx8YmxvZ3xlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519337265831-281ec6cc8514?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8YmxvZ3xlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  </div>
  <div class="images">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472905981516-5ac09f35b7f4?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTR8fGJsb2d8ZW58MHx8MHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1466692476868-aef1dfb1e735?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTh8fGJsb2d8ZW58MHx8MHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499951360447-b19be8fe80f5?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTd8fGJsb2d8ZW58MHx8MHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  </div>
  <div class="images">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472905981516-5ac09f35b7f4?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTR8fGJsb2d8ZW58MHx8MHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1466692476868-aef1dfb1e735?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTh8fGJsb2d8ZW58MHx8MHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499951360447-b19be8fe80f5?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTd8fGJsb2d8ZW58MHx8MHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  </div>

</div>
```

First i want the jquery code to pick first image from each of the images div then the second theen third and so oon. And cycle continues just as reference site and i want to add many rows just by the same code schema.

Comment: And ? what have you tried so far to achieve this ? Where's the javascript/jquery code ?

Comment: just added it. stackoverflow wasn't allowing me to add it. you can unminify it online. please do it and lemme know. thanks

Comment: WHy minify the code ? :) just put YOUR code here. Not a copied code.

Comment: it was my code. I minified because it wasn't posting on the stackoverflow

Comment: let me try again

Comment: its not posting

Comment: It was posted now. Can you please explain a bit what you did inside the jQuery code ? Because it's a bit hard to read.

Comment: okay sure. for the fisrt time when the loop runs. it works fine. like the classes are getting changed and everything. like it picks first image from each div and show and then second and then show and same for third. but when the loop runs for 2nd time or so on it messes up.

Comment: from inspect element i saw classes were there which should be removed so i made a function removeclassess but it doesn't worked

Comment: what is `5e3` ? what is `cycler_` ? why are you using `jQuery(function(i) {` ?  what is the `t` variable ? This still looks like minified code but formatted a bit ( some spaces added )

Comment: cycler_ was with id but it's not using now. i tried some other way with id but failed. anyw its of no use. and 5e3 IDK what it is. some admin did it

Comment: 5e3 should be 5000 or time

Comment: Well you said it's your code. And you don't know what some stuff in that code means ? Please edit your question with code you've written while trying to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm telling you i put the code in editor and there should be the time like 5000 or 1000

Comment: some admin did the change to my code

Comment: Ref here for a simple slide show https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-auto-playing-slideshow/

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  var images = $('.images');
  var imagesLength = $('img',images[0]).length;
  var count = 1;
  setInterval(function() {
    
    images.each(function() {
      var items = $(this).find("img");
      items.each(function(i) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        if (i === count) {
          $(this).addClass("active");
        }
      })
    })
    if (imagesLength - 1 > count) {
      count = count + 1;
    } else {
      count = 0;
    }
  },4000);
})

Comment: that worked for me. Thanks for keep asking questions and 0 help.@MihaiT